# shortest synonym for default value

Tags: variables, coding-style, default, synonym

Seeking the shortest synonym for use as a variable name, which means the "default value".

There is an option: "want" (from dict.org)
But it somehow looks strange. Maybe someone knows a better solution, or would just like to know the opinion of others.

Also http://thesaurus.com/browse/default offer some variants, but its not programming subject.

Am I crazy to choose understandable short variable names, IDs :) But sometimes it takes more time than expected...

Comment: I think if you are going to choose something short over obvious/meaningful you might as well use `D`.  'default' is pretty easy to type.

Comment: yes, its seems that no variants. De-fault its too long. I just write an code with "default" prefix:
    `function loadLazyDefaultData()`

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on a short version, go with `DEF` or `DFLT`. I've seen both used in many languages as a prefix and suffix.

Comment: Yes, I'm use sometime these shortcuts and also "defs" How about proper using these terms: dummy, guess, auto?

Comment: @user1633548 - Auto is the only one of those that is close to being a synonym for default, but I'd still pick default or some abbreviation. Every programmer will know what you mean.

Comment: thefault, dephault, i opted for the first

Comment: 'df' is also a good prefix or acronym for 'default', especially if 'def' can't be used (e.g. - 'def' could mean definition), or 'dflt' isn't recognized and you want to get rid of the squigglies for spelling and such.